# Only positive sums - Random sum generator [JAVA]

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a random sum generator that generators random sums!

The only problem with what I created is, it can generate sums that have a negative result as well. So I want it to only generate sums with positive outcomes.

Example:

```
7-10 = -3
```

My code:

```
number1 = (int)(Math.random()* LT) + 1;
number2 = (int)(Math.random()* LT) + 1;
operator = (int)(Math.random()* OP) + 1;

switch(operator) {
    case 1: 
        operation = "+";
        result = number1 + number2;
        break;
    case 2:
        operation = "-";
        result = number1 - number2;
        break;
    case 3:
        operation = "*";
        result = number1 * number2;
        break;
    case 4:
        operation = "/";
        result = number1 * number2;
        break;
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `LT` and `OP`?

Comment: @iNan `LT` varies from 2-10 and `OP` can be 2 and 4

Comment: what dou you want to display for negative outcomes?

Comment: Why is it that regardless of the value of `operation`, you all your case statements still just do `result = number1 * number2;`

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Actually, I don't want negative outcomes at all.

Comment: @Chris so then, why you don't simply check the result before outputting it?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle So what you are saying is that I should first check if `4-5` has a negative outcome and then not show that at all?

Comment: @Chris didn't you hear of the `if` keyword so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you will always be dealing with positive integers your only issue is checking for negative numbers in your subtraction case. I would also recommend switching to the `Random` class to generate random integers. One way to get around negative results is to flip the numbers you are subtracting.

```
boolean flip = false;
int num1, num2, op, result;
String operation;
Random r = new Random();

num1 = r.nextInt(8)+2;
num2 = r.nextInt(8)+2;
op = r.nextInt(4);    

switch(op) {
case 0:
    // Always be positive.
    operation = "+";
    result = num1+num2
    break;
case 1:
    // Could be negative if num2 is larger than num1. Simply flip the numbers.
    flip = num1 < num2;
    operation = "-";
    result = flip ? num2-num1 : num1-num2;
    break;
case 2:
    // Always be positive.
    operation = "*";
    result = num1*num2;
    break;
case 3:
    // Always be positive.
    operation = "/";
    result = num1/num2;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix you can do is let the random operation complete. I assume you do multiple loops of `{add,sub,mult,divide}`. If the *final* result is negative, convert it back to positive.

But a more distributed random number generation can be done with the java runtime:

```
double d = java.lang.Math.random() * MAX_RANDOM_VALUE;  // MAX_RANDOM_VALUE is a max value you define, like 100000
int result = (int)d;
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned anything about required distribution of outputs, but if it's really as simple as making sure you have no negative outputs, you could pass each output through [`Math.abs()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs-int-) before returning it...

Comment: -Why remove the link @cricket_007?  (I assume you have a valid reason, but it's not one I can guess... I find the "etiquette" of this community to be pretty unpredictable.)- I see you reformatted, not removed.

Comment: No real reason :) Just, preference to put the link to the method that you already referred to

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you want to pick random number from ***the set of positive integers which can be written as a + b  where a and b are integers.*** Since every positive integer between 1 and the maximum value of a+b, can be written like this, you just want to select a random positive integer.

```
int result = new Random().nextInt(maxPossibleSumValue);
```

Comment: Actually, what I'm trying to do is prevent things like `4 - 8` which has a negative outcome. I would only like positive outcomes

Answer (score 0):

Since random number generated would be in the range `0-1`. You will get negative result only when you are subtracting two numbers and `number2` is greater than `number1`. In this case you can simply swap `number1` and `number2` if `number2` is greater than `number1`.